# Is it safe to disable resize_inode on ext4 FS?

Tags: ext4, lvm

I have 2TB spanned LVM ext4 volume which contains large and mostly static files. With "static" I mean they usualy don't change in time. The volume is 99% full, and adding new files becomes very slow operation. As the volume is big enought, the remaining space of 1% is about 25GB, so I want to use it.

I assume my troubles are result of anti-file-fragmentation mechanism incorporated in ext4. To avoid that behvior I want to disable `resize_inode`. I'm not sure am I right it will help me, but I want to try.

Does someone knows is it safe or not to desable `resize_inode` feature?

Command:

```
sudo tune2fs -O^resize_inode /dev/mapper/data-data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like disabling resize_inode is safe, but I don't think it solved my problem. After executing

```
tune2fs -O^resize_inode /dev/mapper/data-data
```

system recomended me to use e2fsck. Here is the result:

```
# tune2fs -O^resize_inode /dev/mapper/data-data
tune2fs 1.41.11 (14-Mar-2010)

Please run e2fsck on the filesystem.

# e2fsck /dev/mapper/data-data
e2fsck 1.41.11 (14-Mar-2010)
/dev/mapper/data-data was not cleanly unmounted, check forced.
Filesystem does not have resize_inode enabled, but s_reserved_gdt_blocks
is 897; should be zero.  Fix<y>? yes

Resize_inode not enabled, but the resize inode is non-zero.  Clear<y>? yes

Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Block bitmap differences:  -(128--1024) ... -(512000128--512001024)
Fix<y>? yes

Free blocks count wrong for group #0 (860, counted=1758).
Fix<y>? yes
.
.
.
Free blocks count wrong (32631947, counted=32649888).
Fix<y>? yes

/dev/mapper/data-data: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/mapper/data-data: 23369/2065792 files (2.6% non-contiguous), 496180576/528830464 blocks
```

Acording to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/184199/is-it-possible-to-enable-online-resizing-after-the-fs-was-created) answer of Hubert Kario, resize_inode is used to allow resize inodes of FS and I am complitly wrong while trying to use it to speed up my disk operations. But the answer of my question is: Yes, it is safe to disable resize_inode.